# Dependency Property Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol, and there is a Datacontext set for it. This usercontrol contains also a Dependency-Property. Now, i want simply bind to this property.

I think the problem has something to do with the wrong datacontext.

The dependency-Property in my usercontrol (called TimePicker) looks like this:

```
public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TimeProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Time", typeof (TimeSpan), typeof (TimePicker));
```

I try to use it like this:

```
<upDownControlDevelopement:TimePicker Grid.Row="1" Time="{Binding Path=TimeValue}" />
```

When i do this i get the following binding error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TimeValue' property not found on 'object' ''TimePicker' (Name='TimePickerControl')'. BindingExpression:Path=TimeValue; DataItem='TimePicker' (Name='TimePickerControl'); target element is 'TimePicker' (Name='TimePickerControl'); target property is 'Time' (type 'TimeSpan')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Greetings Michael

PS: you can download the code at [here](https://drive.switch.ch/public.php?service=files&t=b4dc2bf381788e8801cbc86271873693)

Comment: What is the DataContext set to? And can you post the code for the class that it is set to?

Comment: The DataContext of your TimePicker controls seems to be set to itself. You would however have to set it to a view model instance that has a TimeValue property, or you would set the binding source explicitly.

Comment: If you are setting the DataContext to this (i.e. the TimePicker control) then you need to change the binding to Time="{Binding Path=Time}" if you want to bind it to that property, otherwise as Clemens stated you need to set the DataContext to a view model instance

Comment: There is also no sense in raising a PropertyChanged event in the setter of the CLR wrapper of the Time property. Dependency properties already implement a change notification.

Comment: I've set the DataContext to a ViewModel in the constructor (in the code behind). The other databindings on the Window work without troubles. But i think there is something with the issue that the Datacontext in the control TimePicker is set explicitly.

Comment: Do you set this DataContext on the Window? Does your user control have `DataContext = this;` in the constructor? If so that will override the value from the Window. Have you tried a debugging tool like Snoop to see what the actual DataContext is?

Comment: @vesan I have set the DataContext to the control itself using the following code 'DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}'. But what it need is a chance to override the DataContext at the place where i use the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override the data context of user control. You can use RelativeSource to point your binding source property i.e. TimeValue to any other source you like. E.g. If you have the source property in your window's class. You could simply point your binding target to the source in window's data context as follows:

```
 {Binding Path=DataContext.TimeValue, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Although this has now been solved there seems to be some, in my opinion, inappropriate use of the `DataContext`.

When developing a custom reusable control, you should not set `DataContext` at all. What the `DataContext` will be, that is for the *user* of the control to decide, not for the developer. Consider the following common pattern of code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Data}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue1}" />
    <!-- Some more controls -->
</Grid>
```

Notice that here, you are using the `Grid` control. The developer of the control (in this case, the WPF team), didn't touch the `DataContext` at all - that is up to you. What does it mean for you as a control developer? Your `DependencyProperty` definition is fine, but you shouldn't touch the `DataContext`. How will you then bind something inside your control to the `DependencyProperty` value? A good way is using a template (namespaces omitted):

```
<MyTimePicker>
    <MyTimePicker.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyTimePicker">
            <!-- Stuff in your control -->
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Time}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Time, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    <MyTimePicker.Template>
</MyTimePicker>
```

Note that `TemplateBinding` is always one-way only, so if you need any editing at all, you need to use normal binding (as you can see on the `TextBox` in the example).

This only means that the TextBlock/Box inside your control will get its `Time` value from your custom control itself, ignoring any `DataContext` you might have set.

Then, when you use the control, you do it like this (added to my first example):

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Data}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue1}" />
    <!-- Some more controls -->
    <MyTimePicker Time="{Binding TimeValue}" />
</Grid>
```

What just happened here is that the `MyTimePicker` does not have `DataContext` set anywhere at all - it gets it from the parent control (the `Grid`). So the value goes like this: `Data-->(binding)-->MyTimePicker.Time-->(template binding)-->TextBlock.Text`.

And above all, avoid doing this in the constructor of your custom control:

```
public MyTimePicker()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

This will override any `DataContext` set in XAML, which will make binding a huge pain (because you'll have to always set `Source` manually). The previous example would not work, and this wouldn't work either:

```
<MyTimePicker DataContext="{Binding Data}" Time="{Binding TimeValue}" />
```

You would think this is OK, but the `DataContext` will be resolved in the `InitializeComponent()` call, so the value will be immediately overwritten. So the binding to `TimeValue` will look for it in the control instead (which will, of course, fail).

Just don't touch the `DataContext` when developing a control and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you verry much. You solved many problems that i have with my usercontrol. I would rate you up, but i don't have this privilege yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your error states that *'TimeValue' property not found on 'object' 'TimePicker'*, which means that the WPF Framework is looking at the `'TimePicker'` object to resolve the `'TimeValue'` property value. You must have somehow set the `DataContext` of the `Window` or `UserControl` that contains the `'TimePicker'` object to an instance of the `'TimePicker'` object.

Instead, it should be set to an instance of the class that declares the `'TimeValue'` property. If you're using a view model, then you should set it to an instance of that:

```
DataContext = new YourViewModel();
```

If the `'TimeValue'` property is declared in the `Window` or `UserControl` then you can set the `DataContext` to itself (although generally not recommended):

```
DataContext = this;
```

Please note that when data binding to the `'Time'` property *from inside your `TimePicker` control*, you should use a `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:TimePicker}}}" ... />
```

Comment: Thats exactly the point where i stuck. When you look at the code (i have edited the question) you can see the problem. the usercontol has its own datacontext set and i need to override it

Comment: Show the relevant parts of code here (in your question).

Answer (score 0):

Normally we are not setting datacontext directly.If u want to set datacontext create an instance of your usercontrol and set datacontext individually to each one.