# User Control DataContext/Binding Issue with Dependency Property WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Ok, so my problem is I have a user control. In the xaml I bind some colors to color properties that I have created as shown below.

```
<GradientStop x:Name="stop1" Color="{Binding Color1}" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop x:Name="stop2" Color="{Binding Color2}" Offset="1"/>
```

In my code behind I have a DependencyProperty that I have declared as shown below.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsActive", typeof(bool), typeof(Bin), 
new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(Bin.IsActivePropertyChanged)));
```

The dependency property has a PropertyChangedCallback that it calls called IsActivePropertyChanged as shown below.

```
private static void IsActivePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
            Bin b = (Bin)d;
            if((bool)e.NewValue)

            {
                b.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3E);
                b.Color2 = Colors.Red;
                b.Color3 = Colors.Red;
                b.Color4 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            }
            else
            {
                b.Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3E);
                b.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x83, 0x83, 0x83);
                b.Color3 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63);
                b.Color4 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            }
        }
```

If I use the constructor below, the color changes inside of the constructor work fine, however, my IsActivePropertyChangedEvent never gets fired. I am assuming because of the DataContext assignment in the constructor.

```
 public Bin()
        {
            Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3E);
            Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x83, 0x83, 0x83);
            Color3 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63);
            Color4 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
```

If I comment out the DataContext assignment and use the constructor below, my Color assignments do not work, but the IsActivePropertyChanged event fires fine.

```
public Bin()
            {
                Color1 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x3E, 0x3E, 0x3E);
                Color2 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x83, 0x83, 0x83);
                Color3 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x63, 0x63, 0x63);
                Color4 = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                InitializeComponent();
                //DataContext = this;
            }
```

My question is how can i get the binding to work correctly and have my event fire as well. I have tried setting the `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` (instead of setting the DataContext in the code behind) of the items that are bound to the Color Properties in XAML, a rectangle and a polygon, but that didn't seem to work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When writing your own control, you shouldn't mess with the `DataContext` of the control itself. Instead, on the binding of the GradientStop, you can use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Bin}` (assuming `Bin` is your control). Or you can define a template and use `TemplateBinding`. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476263/dependency-property-datacontext/30496202#30496202) I wrote a while back for a similar question.

Comment: _"my IsActivePropertyChangedEvent never gets fired"_ -- then no one is changing it. Whether that actually has anything to do with your `DataContext` is not possible to say, as you haven't shown how the property would get changed. I can say that from what little code you've posted, it seems likely you should be using a XAML trigger to change the color values, not code-behind. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I am changing the IsActive Property from my viewModel in my main application. Like I said above, it fires every time if I remove the dataContext line in the constructor, but doesn't when I keep that line in. @vesan I will try that when I get in this morning.

Comment: @vesan That worked. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing your own control, you shouldn't mess with the `DataContext` of the control itself.

Instead, on the binding of the `GradientStop`, you can use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Bin}` (assuming Bin is your control). Or you can define a template and use TemplateBinding. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476263/dependency-property-datacontext/30496202#30496202)  I wrote a while back for a similar question - it has more detailed description of how this works.